# how to use temporary table multiple times in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have create temporary table in procedure like as below.

```
create temporary table tmp_table
(
id int,
idate date,
iname varchar(100)
)

insert into tmp_table
select dept_no, dept_create_date,dept_name from dept_record_2016
union all 
select dept_no, dept_create_date,dept_name from dept_record_2017;


select * from tmp_table;

insert into tmp_table
select emp_no , date_of_join , emp_full_name from emp_info;
```

And I getting following error ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'tmp_table'.

So how to use same temporary table in procedure multiple times using single temporary table?

Have an alternative solution?

Comment: when are you getting the error. please edit you question with the error message. good question!

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @PhilippSander I already mention in my question but ERROR 1137: Can't reopen table: 'tmp_table'

Comment: please never post error message in the comments. edit your question

Comment: @DbaOra Any feedback to my answer?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

When I try to reproduce your problem with this procedure, I can not reproduce it. Works perfectly fine for me.

```
delimiter $$
create procedure whatever()
begin
create temporary table tmp_table (a int, b int);

insert into tmp_table
select * from a
union all
select * from b;

select * from tmp_table;

insert into tmp_table
select * from c;
end $$
delimiter ;

call whatever();
```

Describe your problem in much more detail! And try to isolate when exactly the error message appears.

**Original answer:**

I guess your problem is this:

> A TEMPORARY table is visible only to the **current session**, and is
>   dropped automatically when the session is closed. This means that two
>   different sessions can use the same temporary table name without
>   conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of
>   the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table
>   is dropped.)

[Source (official manual)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html#create-temporary-table)

Comment: can you explain me why i can't access temporary table again and again in simple english words?

Comment: Like I said in the answer, I can't reproduce the problem. And I asked you to provide more details. Do you try to access the table from different sessions? What else happens between your access attempts? Whatever you can provide...otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Already I used an example which have "whatever" procedure name and it's call from only once in a session not access from another session.

Comment: Have you googled for any bugs with the MySQL version you're using regarding this issue?