# How to use the same common table expression in two consecutive psql statements?

Tags: postgresql, psql

I'm trying to perform a pretty basic operation with a few steps:

1. `SELECT` data from `table1`
2. Use `id` column from my selected table to remove data from `table2`
3. Insert the selected table from step 1 into `table2`

I would imagine that this would work

```
begin;

with temp as (
  select id
  from table1
)

delete from table2
where id in (select id from temp);

insert into table2 (id)
select id from temp;

commit;
```

But I'm getting an error saying that temp is not defined during my insert step?

Only other post I found about this is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43800150/how-to-use-temporary-table-multiple-times-in-mysql) but it didn't really answer my question.

Thoughts?

Comment: You are not creating a temporary table you are using a CTE. The insert is happening outside the CTE statement so it will not see `temp`. Either include it in the CTE or do `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp ...`.

Comment: Also, the title suggests this question is about accessing the table from two separate transactions, but the example and answer pertains to doing it in a single transaction, misleading people coming here from Google (like myself). I'm changing the title to better reflect what is being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Postgres documentation:

> WITH provides a way to write auxiliary statements for use in a larger
> query. These statements, which are often referred to as Common Table
> Expressions or CTEs, can be thought of as defining temporary tables
> that exist just for one query.

If you need a temp table for more than one query you can do instead:

```
begin;

create temp table temp_table as (
  select id
  from table1
);

delete from table2
where id in (select id from temp_table);

insert into table2 (id)
select id from temp_table;

commit;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, sorry I didn't even know this existed / what CTEs were. Thanks so much <3